# Bing Maps Layers

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, bing-maps

I've been working with bing maps in Silverlight recently and have things at a good working order. One quirk that I would like to resolve is that all of my shapes that are drawn on the page get rendered on top of the road layer and even worse, the city names. So if my shapes are opaque, you can't read them. I'm figuring that there must be some z-index type property involved but I'm having a hard time finding any information about it.

Does anyone know how to set the stack order of the layers provided? Is there a particular index of the existing layers (roads, street names, city names and so on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think so. The base Bing map layers (map, aerial, aerial with labels) are just prebuilt tiled images. Shapes added will be on top of those images.